# Custom widget's template doesn't show up in the front-end

Tags: blocks, widget

So I have a custom widget with block defined in module's config.xml:

```
<config>
 <modules>
    (...)
 </modules>

 <global>
    <blocks>
        <gwidgets>
            <class>Phil_Gwidgets_Block</class>
        </gwidgets>
    </blocks>
 (...)
 </global>
</config>
```

Block's file is under `app/code/local/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php`

I believe this is where the problem starts. I insert the widget into Wysiwyg editor in back-and, refresh the front-end and it doesn't appear. I check system log and there's this error:

`Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php5/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/www/xyz/:/usr/bin/)  in /home/www/xyz/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 145`

So after setting up logging function in functions.php I've found out that these are the directories where autoloader attempts to find by block class:

```
/home/www/xyz/html/app/code/local/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php
/home/www/xyz/html/app/code/community/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php
/home/www/xyz/html/app/code/core/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php
/home/www/xyz/html/lib/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php
./Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php
/usr/share/php5/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php
```

It nearly does it here:

```
/home/www/xyz/html/app/code/local/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php
```

It would find it without '/Mage' in the path.

So the question is why Magento looks for Slider.php in `...local/Mage/...` rather than `...local/....`?

I'd appreciate any advice on how to fix this issue. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767161/warning-file-exists-function-file-exists-open-basedir-restriction-in-effec

Comment: @zhartaunik thanks for the link but I think that my problem has more to do with Magento's way of parsing plugin configuration.

Comment: Show your Slider.php

Comment: @zhartaunik The problem is that Magento can't find Slider.php so I can have anything inside.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears because your php tries to access **/usr/share/php5** directory but server does not allow that. Check permission of **/usr/share/php5** directory.

Answering the question why this folder is in 'include_paths' - check your php.ini configuration and virtual host config maybe it is set there. Default value of `include_paths` is `.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`.

Comment: Thanks Oleksii. You are right. The problem here is that Magento should look for my file in `/home/www/xyz/html/app/code/local/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php` and not `/home/www/xyz/html/app/code/local/Mage/Phil/Gwidgets/Block/Slider.php`. In such case it wouldn't have to look for it in `/usr/share/php5` and the error wouldn't appear. The question is why Magento looks for it in `...local/Mage/...` rather than `...local/....`

Answer (score 0):

I've made two changes to my `widget.xml` file and the problem disappeared:

1) In definition of a widget I've changed type and module name.

```
<gwidgets_slider type="gwidgets/widget_slider" translate="label description" module="gwidgets">
```

2) I've extended template tag from:

```
<template>
 <required>0</required>
 <visible>0</visible>
 <label>Template</label>
 <value>gwidgets/slider.phtml</value>
</template>
```

to:

```
<template>
 <required>0</required>
 <visible>0</visible>
 <label>Template</label>
 <type>select</type>
 <value>gwidgets/slider.phtml</value>
 <values>
  <default translate="label">
   <value>gwidgets/slider.phtml</value>
   <label>Slider template</label>
  </default>
 </values>
</template>
```